# Why is swap called by std::sort only if my container has more than 32 elements?

Tags: c++, std, swap

Hello I have a simple question:

```
class A 
{
public:
    A(int);
    A(const A&);
    A& operator=(const A&);
    ~A();
private:
    int* ptr_;

    friend bool operator<(const A&, const A&);
    friend void swap(A&, A&);
};

A::A(int x) : 
    ptr_(new int(x))
{}

A::A(const A& rhs) :
    ptr_(rhs.ptr_ ? new int(*rhs.ptr_) : nullptr)
{}

A& A::operator = (const A & rhs)
{
    int* tmp = rhs.ptr_ ? new int(*rhs.ptr_) : nullptr;
    delete ptr_;
    ptr_ = tmp;

    return *this;
}

A::~A()
{
    delete ptr_;
}

bool operator<(const A& lhs, const A& rhs)
{
    cout << "operator<(const A&, const A&)" << endl;
    return *lhs.ptr_ < *rhs.ptr_;
}

void swap(A& lhs, A& rhs)
{
    cout << "swap(A&, A&)" << endl;
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs.ptr_, rhs.ptr_);
}

int main()
{

    std::vector<A> v{ 33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22, 21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5, 4,3,2,1 };
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

}
```

With more than 32 elements, the sort calls `swap`. With 32 elements or less, the elements are still sorted but `swap` is not called.

- I am using MSVC++ 2019 on x64.
- When is `swap` called and when is it not and why? Thank you!
- I didn't use `swap` in copy-assignment only to distinguish between the call to it from sort from the copy-assignment operator.

Comment: `std::sort` resorts to insertion sort if the number of elements is 32 or less, and uses quick sort otherwise.

Comment: @Evg Is that a requirement or is that an explanation for this particular context?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, this is an implementation detail of Microsoft standard library. My guess is that this is the reason of the behaviour observed by OP. I'm currently looking into the source code to gain more details.

Comment: Relevant part of the source is: `while (_ISORT_MAX < (_Count = _Last - _First) && 0 < _Ideal)` where `_ISORT_MAX` is given the value of 32. Line 3447 of `<algorithm>` using VS 16.5.0

Comment: No real quicksort is used in any modern standard libraries in any languages. All use modified mixed versions which only is a quicksort when the number of elements is large enough. For example Java and Python use [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) while .NET framework and GCC's C++ library use [Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort). libstdc++ and libc++ also use insertion sort for short sequences. See [What algorithms are used in C++11 std::sort in different STL implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22356687/995714)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Microsoft `std::sort` implementation [looks](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/1e8b8d4eef4b2dddeb7533c5231c876383bd0ea6/stl/inc/algorithm#L3475) like this:

```
const int ISORT_MAX = 32;  // maximum size for insertion sort

template<class RanIt, class Diff, class Pr>
void Sort(RanIt First, RanIt Last, Diff Ideal, Pr Pred)
{
    Diff Count;
    for (; ISORT_MAX < (Count = Last - First) && 0 < Ideal; )
    {   // divide and conquer by quicksort
        pair<RanIt, RanIt> Mid = Unguarded_partition(First, Last, Pred);

        // ...
    }

    if (ISORT_MAX < Count)
    {   // heap sort if too many divisions
        Make_heap(First, Last, Pred);
        Sort_heap(First, Last, Pred);
    }
    else if (1 < Count)
        Insertion_sort(First, Last, Pred);  // small
}
```

When the range to be sorted has 32 elements or less, `Sort` uses insertion sort. Insertion sort doesn't use `swap` in its [implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/1e8b8d4eef4b2dddeb7533c5231c876383bd0ea6/stl/inc/algorithm#L3353). Otherwise, divide-and-conquer quick sort is used. In the [implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/1e8b8d4eef4b2dddeb7533c5231c876383bd0ea6/stl/inc/algorithm#L3408) it calls `iter_swap` (inside `Unguarded_partition`), [which](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/1e8b8d4eef4b2dddeb7533c5231c876383bd0ea6/stl/inc/utility#L41) in turn calls `swap`:

```
template<class FwdIt1, class FwdIt2>
void iter_swap(FwdIt1 Left, FwdIt2 Right)
{   // swap *Left and *Right
    swap(*Left, *Right);
}
```

All these are implementation details. They vary from one standard library implementation to another.

Comment: [libcxx](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/algorithm) uses insertion sort for sequences of length smaller than 6 or 30 depending on the type. [libstd++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h) does that for sequences of 16 elements or less. [What algorithms are used in C++11 std::sort in different STL implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22339240/995714)