# Does std::sort of non primitive data type always return the same sorted array if it contains duplicates as per comparator

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, vector

Suppose I have a non primitive data type with duplicates as per comparator, and I attempt to sort it using `std::sort`...does it give the same sorted array everytime (if we compare the sorted array in every result, will it be same ?). I know it is not stable (it may change the order of equal elements), but is the result of the same input array guaranteed to be deterministic (reliable and reproducible) ?

```
struct Data {
  std::string str;
  int data;
};

struct {
        bool operator()(Data a, Data b) const { return a.data > b.data; }
} customLess;

int main() {
    std::vector v = {
       {"Rahul", 100},
       {"Sachin", 200},
       {"Saurav", 200},
       {"Rohit", 300},
       // .....

    };

    for(uint k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
       auto v2 = v;
       std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(), customLess);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee in the Draft Standard [\[sort\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/sort#lib:sort)  _"...Effects: Sorts the elements in the range [first, last) with respect to comp and proj...."_

Comment: I don't think that property is guaranteed by the standard, so even if it works that way on your current implementation I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Is the contingent upon a seed which depends on time or simply on the gcc version etc...  Or since the standard does not specify any guarantee, the implementation is bound to change .... So, the output will be same if run using the same gcc version ?

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is ["pure"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).
"the function return values are identical for identical arguments" and "the function has no side effects"

Comment: @MooingDuck: The definition of "pure" given by your link wouldn't technically fit (in that the function operates by mutating the arguments, not returning new values; if you called `std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(), customLess);` without reseting `v2` to its original state, there's no guarantee the second sort leaves it unchanged, and in many implementations, it would not), but yeah, it's pretty close to pure, at least by C++ standard library standards.

Comment: [Deterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm) is probably a better fit

Comment: Updated the post with the keyword

Answer (score 7):

If I read you correctly, you're asking whether, despite the lack of *stability*, `std::sort` guarantees *repeatability*; if the same input is provided in the same order, and there are elements that are equal on the compared components, but unequal on others, will said elements always get sorted the same relative to one another?

The answer is **No, `std::sort` make no such guarantees**. Doing so would impose restrictions on implementations that might cause them to perform worse (e.g. implementations based on quicksort couldn't use a random pivot to minimize the occurrence of quicksort's pathological case, where performance is `O(n²)` rather than the average case `O(n log n)`). While a plain quicksort of that design is banned in C++11 (where `std::sort` now requires `O(n log n)` comparisons period, not merely `O(n log n)` average case), it can still form the top-level sort for an introsort-based `std::sort` implementation (a reasonable strategy when the inputs are received from possibly malicious sources and you want to reduce their ability to force excessive recursion followed by slower heapsort), so requiring repeatability would prevent implementations from using a random pivot (or any other sorting strategy with a random component), for a benefit virtually no one cares about.

`std::sort` *means* you don't care about the order of unequal elements that compare equal according to the comparator; they're not going to limit potential optimizations to provide a useless guarantee. Many implementations might, in practice, have repeatable sort order in this scenario, but it's not something code should rely on; if you need repeatability, either:

1. Use `std::stable_sort` (and get an ordering for equal inputs that is repeatable *across* implementations, where `std::sort`, being implemented differently by different vendors, would almost certainly not be repeatable across implementations that chose different algorithms), or
2. Expand your custom comparator to perform fallback sorting that encompasses *all* fields in the input elements, so it's impossible to have any uncertainty unless the fields are 100% equal, not merely equivalent based on the main comparison, which gets you not only repeatability for equal inputs, but repeatability for inputs with the same elements in different order. The actual results might put two completely equal elements in a different order (e.g. you might be able to check `.data()` on a `std::string`, and discover that two string with the same characters end up sorting in different orders), but that's almost never important (and if it is, again, use `std::stable_sort`). In this case, you'd change your comparator to (adding `#include <tuple>` if you're not using it):

   ```
   struct {
           bool operator()(const Data& a, const Data& b) const {
               return std::tie(a.data, a.str) > std::tie(b.data, b.str);
           }
   } customLess;
   ```

   so all fields are compared. Note that I changed the arguments to be `const` references (so you're not copying two `Data` objects for each comparison) and I used `std::tie` to make the fallback comparison efficient and easy to code (`std::tie` lets you use `std::tuple`'s lexicographic sort without having to reimplement lexicographic sorting from scratch, an error-prone process, while still sticking to reference semantics to avoid copies).

Comment: So, if a random pivot is not used in an implementation, it will be contingent only on gcc version ?

Comment: @cryptickey: Well, given that there are far more compilers out there than just GCC, it would depend on rather more than that. Even if all vendors agreed on using [introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) ([a quicksort variant that guarantees `O(n log n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14549428/364696)), and none added a random pivot (which they might do, to reduce the chance they have to fall back to heapsort due to excessive recursion) they'd likely have small changes in implementation that would render the sort non-repeatable across compilers.

Comment: @cryptickey: Can you explain *why* you care? In practice, if you care about repeatability, you just use `std::stable_sort` (which will be guaranteed to produce repeatable results no matter how it's implemented). As long as the elements you're sorting are small and/or support noexcept move semantics (most standard containers do), the incremental cost of `std::stable_sort` is pretty minimal, and it provides strict guarantees in the standard, not just "Well, I checked the implementation once, hope they never change it".

Comment: I used someone's code as library and wrote my own code to achieve some purpose. I have a regression tool kit. I have a C++ executable. It usually used to match. Now today I suddenly see my results are not matching using the same executable. I thought it should match. If they are not matching, does it mean a random pivot is being used, or something else

Comment: @cryptickey: If the library was compiled with one version of `std::sort`, and you're recompiling your code and picking up a different version of `std::sort`, even if both were repeatable sorts, they could be different repeatable sorts. `std::sort` is templated, and the library would effectively have specialized implementation(s) for each type being sorted baked in at compile time; an updated compiler building separate source code that happened to perform the same sort, with a different implementation, could end up producing a final executable with two copies per type that disagree.

Comment: For example, introsort has a pretty simple definition: Quicksort, using median-of-3 pivot (first, middle and last elements of each partition considered) until recursion limit hit or partitions are small enough. If recursion limit hit and partitions are still large, switch to heapsort. Once partitions are small enough, switch to insertionsort. Median-of-3 quicksort, heapsort, and insertionsort are all likely to be implemented the same way by different implementors, but the choice of the recursion limit and the size at which to switch to insertionsort varies (there's no one correct answer).

Comment: From [Wikipedia's description of various introsort implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort#Implementations), in practice, these factors *do* vary. `2×log₂ n` as the recursion limit, and 16 as a threshold for switching to insertion sort are fairly common, but some implementations use median-of-3-medians instead of median-of-3, some change the insertion sort threshold based on whether the types are cheap to swap or not, some use shellsort for small partitions instead of insertionsort, etc. Any changes dramatically alter the results, killing cross-implementation repeatability.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Yeah, I'm going to rewrite that bit (I agree it's misleading).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I've rewritten that part to clarify 1) That's it would be legal to use random pivot quicksort as the initial sorting algorithm for introsort (until recursion limit hit), 2) Explaining why you might choose to do so in the real world (to prevent malicious data sources from being able to reliably trigger deep recursion until heapsort involved, causing a meaningful slowdown on sorting even if it remains `O(n log n)`), and 3) As a result, there are real world cases where requiring repeatability costs you something (potentially) big for a pretty niche use case.